# CPCL command not working with Zebra printer iMZ320 but work with MZ 320

Tags: printing, zebra-printers

The CPCL command which is use to communicate with Zebra Printer MZ 320 is 
not working with iMZ 320 model.

Following is the CPCL command used:

**Works with MZ 320 but not with iMZ 320**

var testPrint = '! 0 200 200 210 1 \r\n' + 'TEXT 4 0 200 100 TESTPRINT' + ' \r\n' + 'FORM \r\n' + 'PRINT\r\n';

**Works for both MZ 320 and iMZ 320**

var barcodeTxt  = "123456789";
var barcode = '! 0 200 200 210 1 \r\n' + 'BARCODE 128 1 1 50 150 10 ' + barcodeTxt + ' \r\n' + 'TEXT 7 0 210 60 ' + barcodeTxt + ' \r\n' + 'FORM \r\n' + 'PRINT\r\n';

It will be helpful if someone provided the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

try

var testPrint = '\r\n! 0 200 200 210 1 \r\n' + 'TEXT 4 0 200 100 TESTPRINT' + ' \r\n' + 'FORM \r\n' + 'PRINT\r\n';

Comment: Still not working ...Can you please suggest anything more?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the iMZ320 is in line mode as it may come configured differently due to the different architecture and application. Also you may have to calibrate the printer for the Mark media you use (see the printer manual).